# NULL reference Exception Xamarin al dar click en un Entry

Tags: xamarin.forms

soy nuevo, este es mi primer post, estoy comenzando a desarrolar en Xamarin Forms y todo iba muy bien hasta que me tope con este error.

Actualmente cargo un ListView con datos obtenidos de una lista List<>

lo he hecho en otras paginas del proyecto y todo ha ido bien, hasta que cuando hago una consulta nueva a la base de datos a través de in Like, si hay resultados todo bien, puedo seguir buscando, pero en un momento al tocar el Entry declarado en Xaml (TXTbuscar) para hacer una nueva consulta, sale este error de null reference Object.

comparto mi código, espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano, muchas gracias.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="empresa.PAGINAS.PRECIOS.ListaXXX">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Buscar"/>           
        <Entry x:Name="TXTbuscar" />
        <Button x:Name="BtnBuscar" CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="Orange"/>
        <Label Text="CODIGO || DESCRIPCION || PRECIO" FontSize="Default" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" x:Name="XMLTitulo"/>
        <ListView x:Name="LsvPrecios">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"  Margin="5">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <BoxView Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="DarkSeaGreen" Opacity="10" CornerRadius="5"/>
                                    <BoxView Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="GhostWhite" Opacity="10" CornerRadius="5"/>
                                    <BoxView Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="GhostWhite" Opacity="10" CornerRadius="5"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding CODIGOX}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Micro" x:Name="5555" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontAttributes="Bold" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding DESCRIPCIONX}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Micro"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontAttributes="Bold" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding PRECIOX}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Micro"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontAttributes="Bold" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout >
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
namespace Empresa.PAGINAS.PRECIOS
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ListaXXX : ContentPage
    {
        public ListaXXX ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            this.TXTbuscar.Text = string.Empty;
            INICIAR();
            LLENAR();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();                
        }

        private void INICIAR()
        {
            LsvPrecios.ItemTapped += LsvPrecios_ItemTapped;    
            BtnBuscar.Clicked += BtnBuscar_Clicked;

        }

        private void BtnBuscar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            PAGINAS_DE_LLANTAS.Infor_para_mediciones.SEARCH_DESCRIPCION = TXTbuscar.Text;

            Navigation.PushAsync(new PAGINAS.PRECIOS.ListaXXX());

        }

        private void LsvPrecios_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            Empresa.DATOS.listaprecios CODIGO_CAST = e.Item as Empresa.DATOS.listaprecios;

            PAGINAS_DE_LLANTAS.Infor_para_mediciones.CODE_PRECIOS = CODIGO_CAST.CODIGOX;

            Navigation.PushAsync(new PAGINAS.PRECIOS.Calculo_Precio());

        }

        private void LLENAR()
        {
            DATOS.DUsuarios.ListaPreciosLoad.Clear();

            DATOS.DUsuarios.ListadoPreciosFuncion();

            LsvPrecios.ItemsSource = DATOS.DUsuarios.ListaPreciosLoad;

        }   
    }
}
```

[image: Esto pasa cuando toco de nuevo el entry e introducir nuevos criterios de búsqueda, ya trate de hace un UNION ALL a nivel de la consulta SQL y dejar siempre con lineas la lista, pero sigue el error, creo que esta ligado al Objeto Entry no a la consulta SQL, esta es una App en una red interna]

Esto pasa cuando toco de nuevo el entry e introducir nuevos criterios de búsqueda, ya trate de hace un UNION ALL a nivel de la consulta SQL y dejar siempre con lineas la lista, pero sigue el error, creo que esta ligado al Objeto Entry no a la consulta SQL, esta es una App en una red interna

Answer (score 0):

Ya he resuelto el problema, en realidad pienso que ha sido algún Bug del propio Xamarin, pero de igual forma el problema se resuelve.

Comparto como lo solucione por si a alguien le sirve.

Me fije que si presionaba de nuevo el botón de búsqueda y recargaba la pagina, el error dejaba de suceder.

por tanto si al encontrar una lista vacía, al momento de la carga de la pagina, mandaba de nuevo a recargar la pagina, el error dejaría de suceder y el control saldría de su estado de NULL, solo hice esta pequeña modificación a la función que llena el ListView.

```
   private void LLENAR()
    {
        DATOS.DUsuarios.ListaPreciosLoad.Clear();

        DATOS.DUsuarios.ListadoPreciosFuncion();

        if(DATOS.DUsuarios.ListaPreciosLoad.Count == 0)
        {
            PAGINAS_DE_LLANTAS.Infor_para_mediciones.SEARCH_DESCRIPCION = TXTbuscar.Text;



            Navigation.PushAsync(new PAGINAS.PRECIOS.ListaXXX());
            LsvPrecios.ItemsSource = DATOS.DUsuarios.ListaPreciosLoad;
        }
        else
        {
            LsvPrecios.ItemsSource = DATOS.DUsuarios.ListaPreciosLoad;
        }






    }
```